# MoveAndSlide() not working with Character stuck in the same place and not moving

Tags: c#, game-physics, game-development, godot, godot4

I'm using Godot4 and although IsOnFloor returns true and my characters movement input are registered the CharacterBody2D doesnt actually move

I have also tried using MoveAndCollide but when I use that ,I find I can't actually jump due to IsOnFloor() always returning false.

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class Player1 : CharacterBody2D
{
    private int gravity = 10;
    private int maxSpeed = 500;
    private int maxFallSpeed = 100;
    public int speed = 200;
    public int jumpForce = 100;
    public Vector2 screenSize;

    private bool jumpCheck = false;
    private float jumpTimer= 0f;
    private float maxJumpTime = 0.5f;

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        screenSize = GetViewportRect().Size;
    
    }

    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
        var velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        if(IsOnFloor()==false)
        {
            velocity.Y += gravity * (float)delta;
        }
        if (IsOnFloor())
        {
            GD.Print("isonfloor = true");
        }
        else
        {
            GD.Print("isonfloor = false");
        }

    
        if (Input.IsActionPressed("left"))
        {
            GD.Print("left");
            velocity.X -= speed; 
        }
        if (Input.IsActionPressed("right"))
        {
            GD.Print("right");
            velocity.X += speed;
        }
        if (Input.IsActionPressed("down"))
        {
            GD.Print("down");
            velocity.Y += speed;
        }
        if(Input.IsActionPressed("jump") )
        {
            GD.Print("jump");
            if(IsOnWall() && !jumpCheck)
            {
                GD.Print("hello");
                jumpCheck = true;
                jumpTimer = 0f;
                velocity.Y = -jumpForce;
            }
        
            else if (jumpCheck && jumpTimer < maxJumpTime)
            {
                GD.Print("jump2");
                jumpTimer += (float)delta;
                velocity.Y = -jumpForce;
            }
            else 
            {
                GD.Print("jump3");
                jumpCheck = false;
            }
                

        }
    
        MoveAndSlide();
        //velocity = velocity.Normalized() * speed;
        //MoveAndCollide(velocity * (float)delta);
    }
}
```

Here's what happens when I run:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnjP6.png]

Comment: I think _Process() should be _Physics_Process(),